# Is it a good idea/practice to store large objects in job execution context

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

We are working on a spring batch application which processes 4-5 million records. We have multiple steps configured in the job. Out of that 2 steps are fetching large data and we are storing few information from that data in Jobexecution context in prcessors's after step.

```
 @AfterStep
    public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution)
    {
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().put("FETCH_2_CURSOR", rptObj);
}
```

So that data can be referred in last step to perform some calculation.

The job runs **successfully when we are using postgres DB as a job repository**, However it **fails when we are using db2 LUW as a job repository** on the second fetch data step.

I have read in some forums that large objects should not be written to the ExecutionContext.

Anyone can suggest is it a good idea to store large data in job execution context? Or shall we serialize that obj in file system and then refer in final step?

Error :

Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT SET SHORT_CONTEXT = ?, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT = ? WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?]; The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.19.26; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statement is out of range for its corresponding use.. SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.19.26

Answer (score 0):

It's not suggested to add a lot of data in ExecutionContext.Even though if you add, you will get an exception at runtime.

the SERIALIZED_CONTEXT column has limit about  65kb

This has been answered in Spring Batch forum.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/126318-data-truncation-data-too-long-for-column-serialized-context-at-row-1

Comment: Good answer, useful, however forum is now dead and effectively the link too.
I arrived here looking for good ways to report back larger extraneous information from Spring Batch to Spring Integration... paths / buckets / keys of affected "things"